# Import vars/consts from main in subpackage

Tags: go

I have a Go project at **`$GOPATH/dalu/myproject`** with the following files :

**`main.go`**:

```
package main

import "dalu/myproject/subpackage"
var GV string = "World"

func main() {
    subpackage.Hello()
}
```

**`subpackage/subpackage.go`**:

```
package subpackage

import (
    "fmt"
    "dalu/myproject"
)

func Hello() {
    //? fmt.Println("Hello"+GV)
}
```

Bonus (if I could):
I tried something similar with more subpackages and when trying to import a subpackage in main that imports another subpackage which imports the first mentioned subpackage I get "import cycle not allowed"

Comment: Did you try myproject.GV

Comment: @fuz it works for me. But, can you tell how to do that if "myproject" is `my-project`?

Comment: @roshnet The identifier to use is the identifier in the package clause of the package you want to import.  If you don't know what it is, you can use a qualified import like `import my_project "my-project"`.

Comment: sure @fuz, thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

As the compiler so nicely said, Go doesn't allow cyclic dependencies, and unlike C++ there are no forward declarations tricks to be done here.

if you have a state where:
`A imports B AND B imports A`

it measns you need to move whatever they share between them to package `C`, and do:
`A imports B, C AND B imports C`

and everyone's happy!

or in your example, add a file called `dalu/myproject/gv/gv.go` and in it define this `GV`. Then import it in both `main` and `subpackage`

Comment: thanks it answers the question. regarding the bonus, I tried something like this: https://github.com/dalu/gobfw/tree/master/module/user where I defined the routes in routes/routes.go , imported handler and imported routes in user.go and it would give me the circular dependency message. I'll upload a better example tomorrow

Comment: https://github.com/dalu/deptest is what I meant. Should I create a new question for this? Ah I get it, your answer actually answer that question. I need to create a subpackage of globals named, let's say routes and define routes there. Ok question answered. thanks alot :)